# php5 script upgrade - foreach inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to upgrade a script from PHP4 to PHP5 and I'm having an issue with foreach. I have looked online and haven't been able to find anything which works for my script.

Basically, the issue is that `$filmid` on line 9 and `$event['venueID']` on line 13 are not recognised and the array returns empty.
I can make it work by assigning values to `$filmid` and `$event['venueID']` but obviously that completely defeats the point.

So basically, how can I rewrite these for my script to work?
if($event['titleID'] == $filmid ){ 
and
if($venue['venueID'] == $event['venueID']){

Here is the data I'm using:

```
<listing>
<venueList>
<venue venueID="vxappfil">
</venue>
</venueList>
<titleList>
<title titleID="txgrewhi3">
<titleName>The Great White Silence</titleName>
</title> 
</titleList>
<eventList>
<event titleID="txgrewhi3" venueID="vxappfil">
<startDate>03/08/2012</startDate>
<endDate>09/08/2012</endDate>
<times>Sun 19:00</times>
</event>
</eventList>
</listing>
```

Here are the codes:

```
foreach ($thisweeksxml->titleList->title as $title) {
    $filmid = $title['titleID'];
    ......


    $thiweekscinemasnamesarray = array();
    foreach ($thisweeksxml->eventList->event as $event) { 

        if($event['titleID'] == $filmid ){

            foreach ($thisweeksxml->venueList->venue as $venue) {

                if($venue['venueID'] == $event['venueID']){


                    $cityname = strtolower(str_replace ($removeChars, "", $venue->venueAddress->town));
                    $venuname = strtolower(str_replace ($removeChars, "", $venue->venueName));
                    $thiweekscinemasnamesarray[] = ("- <a href='/cinema/".$cityname."-".$venuname.".html'><font size='-2' style='line-height:15pt'>".$venue->venueAddress->town.", ".$venue->venueName."</font></a>");

                }

            }   

        }

    }

    sort($thiweekscinemasnamesarray);
    foreach($thiweekscinemasnamesarray as $lastweek){

    $bodycontent .="".$lastweek."<br>";

}
```

Comment: Can you do var_export($thisweeksxml); and post the result here so we have something to work with?

Comment: Is titleList->title an array?

Comment: $thisweeksxml is a simple XML doc loaded on our server. Here is an example:
titleList->title isn't an array, it's an entry in the file

Comment: you say you're upgrading to PHP5, but what are you upgrading *from*?

Comment: XML can change and that will make change the simplexmlelement object. So you must not have these properties / array entries there. Check them first.

Comment: I'm upgrading from php4 so the codes used to work. 
I know I'm not meant to have a foreach in a foreach in php5. I just don't know what to replace it with.

Comment: Here is the structure of the feeds: <listing> <venueList> <venue venueID="vxappfil"> </venue> </venueList> <titleList> <title titleID="txgrewhi3"> <titleName>The Great White Silence</titleName> <certificate>U</certificate> </title> </titleList> <eventList> <event titleID="txgrewhi3" venueID="vxappfil"> <startDate>03/08/2012</startDate> <endDate>09/08/2012</endDate> <times>Sun 19:00</times> </event> </eventList> </listing>

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a } at the last foreach loop

Comment: given that he says "...the array returns empty" in the question, I can assume that the code at least runs for him, which rules this out as the actual problem. (I would guess it's a copy+paste error when he was transcribing the code into the question)

Comment: The codes used to work absolutely fine with PHP4, I just forgot the } when I copied them. I know I can't have a foreach in a foreach with PHP5. I just can't figure out how to rewrite that bit of the code.

Comment: @user1595256 - of course you can have nested foreach loops in PHP5. Who on earth told you you couldn't???

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really sufficient information to work on here, but my guess would be that the vars you're accessing as arrays are actually objects.

Therefore I would suggest changing:

```
$event['titleID']
```

into

```
$event->titleID
```

If this works, great. If it doesn't work, then you'll need to show us more about the structure of `$thisweeksxml`, by providing the output of `var_dump($thisweeksxml)` or `print_r($thisweeksxml)`. (edit it into the original question)

Comment: Here is the stricture of the feeds:


<listing>
<venueList>
<venue venueID="vxappfil">
</venue>
</venueList>


<titleList>
<title titleID="txgrewhi3">
<titleName>The Great White Silence</titleName>
<certificate>U</certificate>
</title>
</titleList>


<eventList>
<event titleID="txgrewhi3" venueID="vxappfil">
<startDate>03/08/2012</startDate>
<endDate>09/08/2012</endDate>
<times>Sun 19:00</times>
</event>
</eventList>
</listing>

Comment: @user1595256 - please edit the question to include that data; it'll be much easier to read that way.